# Add new fields to context variable in strapi backend for user management

Tags: node.js, auth0, strapi

I am using strapi as backend and react in the front-end. So the use case is that the user will signup and that signup will be done using auth0. I have defined some roles for the users signing up as shown on auth0
[Roles based on plan taken by user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDdA6.png)

```
const _ = require("lodash");
const axios = require("axios");
const jwt = require("../jwt");
module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
let role;
if (ctx.state.user) {
// request is already authenticated in a different way
return next();
}
try {
const tokenInfo = await axios({ method: "post",
url: `${process.env.AUTH0_URL}/userinfo`,
headers: { Authorization: ctx.request.header.authorization,
          },
        });
let user_id = tokenInfo.data.sub;
var config = { method: "get",
url: `${process.env.AUTH0_URL}/api/v2/users/${user_id}/roles`,
headers: {Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt.jwtSecret}`,
          },
        };

axios(config).then(function (response) {
ctx.state.roles = response.data[0].name; // This part does not work in the next policy as ctx.state.role gives undefined in route specific policy
          }).catch(function (error) {
console.log(error);
          });
//   console.log(tokenInfo.data, "tokeninfo");
if (tokenInfo && tokenInfo.data) {
return await next();
        }
      } catch (err) {
console.log(err.message);
return handleErrors(ctx, err, "unauthorized");
      }
```

Currently these will be managed here only. Now I have a collection which has some research articles which can only be accessed depending upon the plan user has been assigned. In order to protect the route and strapi access I have installed user-permissions plugin in strapi and managing userinfo using a global policy as shown

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Irr2n.png)
. So here is the code through which I am checking the user info on every route

Now there are two ways in which I tried solving my problem. First I read the tokenInfo data from userInfo route but unfortunately auth0 is not returning roles assigned. It is only returning standard data like

```
"name": "ansh5@gmail.com",
"nickname": "ansh5",
"picture": "https://s.gravatar.com/avatar/6fdb83f10321dd7712ac2457b11ea34e? 
 s=480&r=pg&d=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn.auth0.com%2Favatars%2Fan.png",
"updated_at": "2021-07-19T08:03:50.461Z",
"user_id": "auth0|60ec0b3721224b0078ac95f4",
```

So in order to get user role I used the other API and configured it with my auth0 account.
 
     ${process.env.AUTH0_URL}/api/v2/users/${user_id}/roles

 I am getting the correct response but when I am doing this assignment.

```
ctx.state.roles = response.data[0].name;
```

I am getting undefined in my ctx.state.roles in my route specific policy. Does anybody have idea how we manage strapi and auth0 together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's because the `axios` calls are `asynchronous` in nature. So as per your code, `axios` will try to get the user information over a network call, but `strapi` will not really wait for the response. Instead it will just move forward to the next policy, hence resulting in an undefined user role. To fix this, you need to `await` for the api response from `axios`. Try the code below:

```js
const axios = require("axios");
const jwt = require("../jwt");
module.exports = async (ctx, next) => {
  let role;
  if (ctx.state.user) {
    // request is already authenticated in a different way
    return next();
  }
  try {
    const tokenInfo = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: `${process.env.AUTH0_URL}/userinfo`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: ctx.request.header.authorization,
      },
    });
    let user_id = tokenInfo.data.sub;
    var config = {
      method: "get",
      url: `${process.env.AUTH0_URL}/api/v2/users/${user_id}/roles`,
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt.jwtSecret}`,
      },
    };

    const resp = await axios(config);
    ctx.state.roles = response.data[0].name;
    console.log(ctx.state.roles);
   
    //   console.log(tokenInfo.data, "tokeninfo");
    if (tokenInfo && tokenInfo.data) {
      return await next();
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
    return handleErrors(ctx, err, "unauthorized");
  }
}
```